Minimum permission needed to Migrate a user from exchange server to 365
I am planning to assign permission to a helpdesk tech so that they can create an on-premise exchange server user, and then they can migrate that user to 365. We dont want to give them Admin rights unless necessary. What sort of minimum permissions are needed on each of these environment so that they can create and migrate users.

In a hybrid deployment; The user that do the task must be at least member of theses groups in the local Active Directory;
Member of the Organization Management & Recipients Management group.
Note; It's a big right to give to a helpdesk staff that you dont want to give admin right. You must thrust them.

and

ref; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/permissions/feature-permissions/recipient-permissions?view=exchserver-2019 & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipient-management-exchange-2013-help?view=exchserver-2019
